# How can I get the number of contents of a dm_document?

Tags: documentum, documentum-dfc

I am trying to add a new content to my `dm_document` with the **DFCMethod** :

```
myDocument.setContentEx(myByteArrayOutpuStream, myContentExtension, pageNumber)
```

However, when I add this content, I don't know if there are other contents already added to this `dm_document` object. In other words, I don't know the value of the pageNumber parameter. I did not find any method such as a getLastContentIndex to perform on my `dm_document`.

How can I know the value to give for the parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method your are looking for is `int getPageCount()`.
You can also get the main content format (content type) name by the method `String getContentType()`.

Then you can use received values as parameters in a call of the `ByteArrayInputStream getContentEx(String format, int pageNumber)` metod which gets the document content from the repository for the given format and page number.

By the `boolean setContentEx(ByteArrayOutputStream content, String format, int pageNumber)` method of `IDfSysObject` you can set primary content as multiple pages. But all pages must be in the same format. If you try to use the method with a different format then it will overwrite the previous content.